# How can I improve this vowel counter function for higher efficiency?

Tags: javascript

This code works, but I was wondering if it was possible to receive some advice on how to make this function run faster.

I have used regular expressions as well as the match method because they seem straightforward to me.

```
const vowelCount = str => {
  let vowels = /[aeiou]/gi;
  let result = str.match(vowels);
  let count = result.length;

  console.log(count);
};
```

The function will display the number of vowels inside a string.

Comment: As a side note, your function will break if there are no vowels in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop or foreach is marginally faster but it is so minor that you aren't really looking at much benefit by moving here.

However here are some faster options.

**Your Code (timed): ~0.185 ms**

```js
const vowelCount = str => {
  let vowels = /[aeiou]/gi;
  let result = str.match(vowels);
  return result.length;
};

var t0 = performance.now();
vowelCount("aSdDDDdasDD");
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call took: " + (t1 - t0) + " MS");
```

**For-Loop (timed): ~.070 ms**

```js
const vowelCount = str => {
    var vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU';
    var count = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < str.length ; x++) {
       if (vowels.indexOf(str[x]) !== -1){
          count += 1;
       }
    }
    return count;
};

var t3 = performance.now();
vowelCount("aSdDDDdasDD");
var t4 = performance.now();

console.log("Call took: " + (t4 - t3) + " MS");
```

**For-Each (timed): ~.074 ms**

```js
const vowelCount = str => {
    var vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU';
    var count = 0;
    Array.from(str).forEach((c) => {
        if(vowels.indexOf(c)) {
           count++;
        }
    });
    return count;
};

var t3 = performance.now();
vowelCount("aSdDDDdasDD");
var t4 = performance.now();

console.log("Call took: " + (t4 - t3) + " MS");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing me with these different versions. I'm new to JavaScript so this really helps. I'll also keep in mind the use of performance.now() to calculate performance speed.